# Error: [ng:areq] when trying to load data from WEB API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, asp.net-web-api2

I've created an Angular Module, Service & Controller which are minified into one file with grunt. The directory is scripts/profile/xxxxx.js It looks as follows:

**Module**:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('profileModule', ['profileServices']);
})();
```

**Service**:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var profileServices = angular.module('profileServices', ['ngResource']);

profileServices.factory('Profiles', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
      return $resource('/api/profiles/', {}, {
          query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
      });
  }]);
})();
```

**Controller**:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('profileModule')
    .controller('profileController', profileController);

profileController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Profiles'];

function profileController($scope, Profiles) {
    $scope.profiles = Profiles.query();
}
})();
```

Grunt config to minify:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
// load Grunt plugins from NPM
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

// configure plugins
grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
        my_target: {
            files: {
                'wwwroot/portal-min.js': [
                    'scripts/profile/profileModule.js',
                    'scripts/profile/profileController.js',
                    'scripts/profile/profileServices.js',
                    'scripts/**/*.js']
            }
        }
    },

    watch: {
        scripts: {
            files: ['scripts/**/*.js'],
            tasks: ['uglify']
        }
    }
});

// define tasks
grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify', 'watch']);
};
```

**WEB API Controller**:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ProfilesController : Controller
{
    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Profile> Get()
    {
        return new List<Profile> {
            new Profile
            {
                Id=1,
                FirstName = "Star Wars",
                LastName= "Lucas",
                Email = "test@test.be"
            },
            new Profile
            {
                Id=2,
                FirstName ="King Kong",
                LastName ="Jackson",
                Email = "test@test.be"
            },
            new Profile
            {
                Id =3,
                FirstName ="Memento",
                LastName ="Nolan",
                Email = "test@test.be"
            }
        };
    }
}
```

When running it I keep getting a Error:

> [ng:areq] Argument 'profileController' is not a function, got
>   undefined

Does this have to do with the minifying or what is the issue? I really don't see it. Just started with AngularJS so any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to include the controller js file to the index.html

```
<script src="path_to_controller/profileController.js"></script>
```

Comment: I included the minified javascript file which holds all the files in the script folder (so normally the controller as well). Could it be an issue with minifying though?

Comment: have you tried it with the unminified version to see if you get the same error?

Comment: Works then .. so the issue is with minifying.

Comment: Going to accept this since it led me to noticing it wasn't properly minified :). Though I had included my minified JS.